# Analysis Calculated Field "Starts With" Filter logic

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to created a calculated field for a countIf and filter on if a field "starts with" or is "like" 'Hello'.  I can't find if a wildcard can be used either, for example:  = Hello%.

The calculated field would look similar to this
distinct_countIf({my_id},{my_value} = 2 AND {my_text} starts with 'Hello')

I can use a filter in the analysis, but I wanted to create a calculated field on the analysis instead of doing a filter so that I can have independent columns of counts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the closest thing you can use is the [`locate`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/locate-function.html) function.

Its indexing appears to be 1-based and `start` is optional in its signature:

```
locate(expression, substring, start)
```

So to emulate "starts with" you should be able to do the following

```
locate({my_text}, 'Hello') = 1
```

To emulate `contains` (which I think is like your `like` case) you could check that it is not `0` (a sentinel value indicating "not found")

```
locate({my_text}, 'Hello') <> 0
```